# Generate random values given 2d pdf

Tags: python, scipy

How to use `rv_continuous` for multidimensional pdf?
Is `rv_continuous` able to handle multidimensional pdf?
My goal is to use the `rvs` method to generate random values from an arbitrary 2d distribution. Do you know any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rv_continuous` only handles univariate distributions.

Comment: fine, alternatives?

Comment: DIY I guess. Or work towards https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3747